# Counting Records In JSON Files

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

OK, I've got a script that runs against different API engines to audit and modify user license assignments.  For the most part, I have the thing pretty well tightened up and working.. but I'm now getting into some of the reporting nuances and I'm struggling.

Depending on the day, how AD Synchronization has gone, which customer account I'm working on, and which platform I'm talking to.. I'll have to paginate through anywhere from 2 to 500,000 user records.  I'm writing all the paginations to files, which I'll work from and then archive for recording keeping.  .. but what I'd really like to do is put a function together that could walk through all the record files in a given directory with a given extension ('.rec') and tell me how many records the script processed. Each record has a unique value identifier (item[id]).

My original bash prototype did this really simply:

```
totalrecords="$(cat $workingDir/$today*.rec | jq . | grep -i '"id":' | wc -l)"
```

How would I pull this off in Python 2.7?

Comment: In python that take about dozen lines and requires the knowledge of your json object structure. i'd rather add echo totalrecords to your script and put something like this in the python code: import subprocces ... tot_rec = subprocess.check_output(["path/to/your_script.sh"])

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped someone else would have a brilliant idea on how to process this.. but since nobody has offered up as much, I’m just going to add a counter variable to all the individual scripts and have them report to keys in a json file that I can then go and read for statistics.